# Use custom component from imported module

Tags: angular

I've created a component named `MultipleIdentifier` to be used in a reactive form using `formControlName`. It was used in a module named `Module1` and declared in this module's `declarations` array.
It worked fine.

Now, in the same app, I want to use this component in an other module named `Module2`.
This component was moved to module named `Components.module` and this new module was imported in `app.module` so it could be used by the two modules `Module1` and `Module2`.
It was exported like this :

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
   MultipleIdentifier,
],
imports: [
   ...
],
exports: [
   MultipleIdentifier,
]
})
export class Components {
}
```

It is compiling fine but, now, none of `Module1` and `Module2` displays the component and both displays the error : `No value accessor for form control with name:` multipleIdentifierInput`(where multipleIdentifierInput is my`MultipleIdentifier` component).
My component is using the expecting provider like this :

```
@Component({
selector: 'multiple-identifier',
templateUrl: './multiple-identifier.component.html',
providers: [
   {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
     multi: true,
     useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleIdentifier)
   },
]
})
export class MultipleIdentifier implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
...
}
```

What am I missing ? It seems that this component is "recognized" but can't be used anymore as a reactive from input field.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out this doc : https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules
I had to import the `Components` module to both `Module1` and `Module2` and import `FormsModule`.
Now everything works